# Momentum of a gas expanding into a vacuum chamber in outer space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, vacuum, gas

Consider a gas expanding adiabatically from a gas chamber through an orifice into a vacuum chamber as shown in the schematic figure. In order for significant number of gas molecules (which we refer to as particles for simplicity), to transition into the vacuum chamber, the center of mass of the collection of all the gas particles must have a velocity which points rightwards towards the vacuum chamber. We assume that the container shown in the figure below is placed far away from all other physical objects, say in outer space, so that there are no external forces acting on it or it's contents.

> How is linear momentum conserved during the transient phase of
> expansion of the gas from it's resting chamber to the vacuum chamber?

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$ [image]

Comment: If you imagine the vacuum chamber to be space, and the "gas chamber" (cough) a rocket, you may get an idea. Famously, the center of mass of a "rocket" ("rocket" being the entirety of its mass, including fuel, at "standstill" before ignition) never moves, because -- how could it?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the analogy you provided is insightful. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At any moment there will be particles moving in each direction, bouncing on the walls and changing direction. The pressure on the walls of the chamber is due to this bouncing.

Those who go through the hole are not reflected by the wall. Thus though the pressure rapidly equalizes in the entire left chamber, the force on the left-hand-side wall is the pressure times the entire surface, while on the right-hand-side wall, the pressure acts on the surface **minus** the size of the hole. It thus transmits a non vanishing total force on the left hand side chamber.

As long as the amount of gas in the right hand side chamber is small, during the transient phase, there is no compensating force on the right-hand-side chamber. The entire solid box, during the transient phase, receives a total momentum to the left, and if not connected to any object, (floating in the vacuum ?) it will move to the left.

When pressures are equalized in both chambers, the total force on the solid box as a whole is zero. Not only that, but since the gas has stopped moving as a whole, the right hand side chamber has finally given back to the gas all the momentum the left hand side chamber had received at the beginning, so there is no momentum left, neither in the gas nor in the solid and all macroscopic motion **stops.**

But the box as a whole will have moved left before stopping, by just the amount needed for the center of mass of the whole thing, box plus gas, to stay put.

If the box is on a table, for instance, friction will resist to its motion, but some momentum is transmitted to the table and from the feet of the table to the ground.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please consider commenting on the following observation on your answer. In the answer it is mentioned that "and all macroscopic motion stops". However, it is not clear why microscopic motion will stop since an intuitive expectation may be that the motion of the gas-and-adiabatic-chamber coupled masses is akin to two connected masses connected by a spring. Due to the adiabatic nature of the system described in the OP, the analogous two spring-mass system has no viscous losses due to which the system will undergo macroscopic oscillation conserving their energy. (1/1)

Comment: In other words, if the statement "and all macroscopic motion stops" is accurate, it would be great if you would comment on the macroscopic process of the conversion of the initial total mechanical energy of the gas-and-adiabatic-chamber system which is equal to the potential energy (PE) of the gas, being converted to a split between kinetic energy (KE) and PE of the system, and finally converted back to the initial PE. (2/2)

Comment: @kbakshi314 The point is that a gas in an **adiabatic situation** is exactly the **opposite** of a system with no "viscous losses". Viscous losses are dominant rather than a small correction. More precisely, the mean free path of a particle between two collisions is typically extremely small compared to the dimension of a "man-usable" box. Even if the first original jet of particles bounces off the right-hand-side wall of the vacuum chamber, most of them will bounce on the separation wall. Very, very few will ever go through the hole ! Where do you see anything like a two spring-mass system ?

Comment: @kbakshi314 You wrote "However, it is not clear why microscopic motion will stop " I assume this is a misprint.  You mean "macroscopic", right ? To go back to your question all the KE of the gas that went into the initial "vacuum" chamber will rapidly dissipate **there** and never induce any return into the left-hand-side one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The word "microscopic" is a typo and should be replaced with the accurate "macroscopic" in the comment labeled (1/1) above (which should in fact be labeled (1/2)). I understand your response to my technical question and appreciate it. However, if we assume that the gas is ideal, are viscous forces still dominant? (1/2)

Comment: Moreover, would you please verify if my understanding that, the viscous dissipation of the KE results in that energy being stored as the PE of the gas, is accurate? Is a two mass spring-mass-damper (and not spring-mass) analogy, assuming that the damper considered can store heat energy (to reflect the adiabatic assumption), more accurate? (2/2)

Comment: An additional clarification on the spring-mass analogy is that the intention with that, although inaccurate, analogy, was to describe the oscillation of the gas-and-adiabatic-chamber (the adiabatic chamber represents the gas chamber and vacuum chamber rigid body) about their center of mass. Finally, this analogous system does describe the bullet-and-gun analogies that other comments or the answer other than yours have used to intuitively explain the system in the OP. It would be great if you could comment on those as well. Thanks!

Comment: What if we look at it in the container's frame of reference?  Does the expansion of the gas cause the outside universe to move?  Is this consistent with the stipulation that the system does not interact with the rest of the universe?

Comment: @JohnBollinger What do you call "the container frame of reference" ? The container is first accelerated then decelerated. Its "frame of reference" is **not** inertial. Calculations in a non inertial referential are famously difficult. I am not an expert in General Relativity, I leave the calculations to you.

Comment: @kbakshi314 I cannot keep commenting on all the comments! Briefly a) the "bullet and gun" analogy is great to describe the **initial** acceleration of the whole container when the gas just begins to move out. But the many, many bullets do not fly away, they bounce on the far wall, then back on the separation wall (except for very few ones that happen to go through the hole), then back, etc. etc.  So the full situation is more complex than an "ordinary bullet and gun". But since the gas keeps coming in, there will be no oscillations, there are always a new bullet "in" for each reflected one.

Comment: b) ideal gas : this is somehow not a very realistic notion. At the same time, it means the particles have zero volume there is no interaction energy between them, the only energy is kinetic energy, **but also** it self-thermalises very fast. Because "adiabatic" which is often understood a "so rapid that there is no time to exchange heat with the exterior" really means "so slow that the gas itself is, at each instant, in thermal self-equilibrium ". So particles interact very, very much, (with no interaction energy !). It is a model which is essentially  self-contradictory, but hugely useful.

Comment: @kbakshi314 About KE energy of the gas that went into the initially empty chamber. It is at least in part **macroscopic motion** KE. That will be transformed, not into **PE**, but into KE energy of **microscopic** molecular motion, that is, heat. There is no PE anywhere ! Only KE of initially microscopic motion, transformed into macroscopic KE at the opening of the hole, and finally turned back into microscopic motion by the very rapid interaction-without-interaction-energy of the "ideal gas" !

Comment: @Alfred thank you so much for the detailed responses to the interesting follow-up discussion in the comments to the answer! Your explanations are impeccable. Thanks! A minor point to note is that the macroscopic PE referred to, in one of the previous comments asking follow-up questions, is the internal (*specific heat* or temperature related) PE of the gas which, in fact simply refers to the microscopic KE of the gas particles.

Answer (score 3):

Because the gas imparts a transient recoil to the enclosure.

It is no different, in principle, to a pellet being fired from an air gun and hitting a mesh welded over the opening of the barrel. The expanding air forces the pellet along the barrel causing a recoil. When the pellet hits the mesh it causes an impulse on the gun opposite to the direction of the original recoil.  We end up with the centre of gravity of the gun/pellet unchanged, but the gun will be displaced backwards somewhat and the pellet displaced forwards.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is often refereed as **Adiabatic free expansion of a gas** or [Joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion)

I would like to quote the page [Adiabatic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Adiabatic_free_expansion_of_a_gas) from wikipedia

> For an adiabatic free expansion of an ideal gas, the gas is contained in an insulated container and then allowed to expand in a vacuum. Because there is no external pressure for the gas to expand against, the work done by or on the system is zero. Since this process does not involve any heat transfer or work, the first law of thermodynamics then implies that the net internal energy change of the system is zero. For an ideal gas, the temperature remains constant because the internal energy only depends on temperature in that case. Since at constant temperature, the entropy is proportional to the volume, the entropy increases in this case, therefore this process is irreversible.

Extensive description can be found in [Joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion) (see note number 3).

So to conclude, no work against the environment during the expansion, means no change in quantities such as momentum, energy, temperature ...